# How to evaluate extrema of a vector field?

Tags: vector-analysis, maxima-minima, fluid-dynamics

I have a velocity vector with components in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions. Each component is some function of $x$, $y$ and $z$. How would I evaluate the location, (cartesian coordinates) of the maximum speed (extrema)?

Here is an example where gamma, $\gamma$, is a constant:

$$\mathbf{u}_3=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4\gamma^2+\pi^2}}\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\gamma\cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)\cos(\gamma z)\\\pi\sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)\sin(\gamma z)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Velocity is a vector. What do you mean by a maximum velocity? (How do you compare two vectors and say one is bigger than the other?) Do you mean instead maximum _speed_?

Comment: Sorry yes, speed.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions. I took the liberty to add your equation to give you an example of mathjax usage.

Comment: The speed is a scalar function; so you can find its extrema by first taking its gradient and looking for where it vanishes. In this case I would suggest looking at the square of the speed since the algebra is a bit simpler.

Comment: So taking the derivative wrt x,y and z of the speed, equating each to zero and finally solving the system of equations?